# Disable double-click to maximize in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, window-manager

In OS X Yosemite, a new feature is that when you double-click on the title bar of an application window, the window will maximize: http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/28/maximize-zoom-windows-os-x-mac/

Is there a way to disable this behavior?  I am accidentally double-clicking and maximizing terminal and VirtualBox VM windows, and this sometimes causes problems.

Comment: I have been trying to figure how to disable this feature and it seems that double click either maximizes or minimizes, and nothing in between.

Answer (score 11):

While I haven't found a way to turn it off completely, you can make it minimize instead by enabling:

> System Preferences > Dock > Double-click a window's title bar to minimize.

Comment: Worth noting that in the same location it's now possible to turn it off completely.

Answer (score 4):

Jacob had it right - in this system pref area you can simply uncheck to box, disabling both double-click to minimise & zoom.

System Preferences > Dock > Double-click a window's title bar to...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If a third-party solution is acceptable, the free [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) allows you to change the effect of this action.

Here is how to disable the maximize action:

[image: screenshot]

If you'd like to keep the functionality, and just want to avoid accidentally triggering it, consider setting up an action for double-clicking the titlebar while holding a modifier key.